# how to update the json file from extjs

Tags: json, extjs

Can you please tell me how I can update the data from my extjs datagrid to JSON file?. My code works fine for loading static data from JSON file. Also, the data gets updated when I edit the data. But I am not aware how to store the updated data to JSON file so that it will be reflected even when I do page refresh or bounce my server.

Thanks

Murali S

Answer (score 1):

You can't just update a json file, something on the server (PHP, Java, C#, other) need to do it. If you could just directly update a static file from the client, it would be a giant security hole.

There are examples in the Ext JS SDK that show you how to send data to the server and persist it.

Comment: Thanks Evan. I will look into the examples.